# How to find area enclosed by this curve?

Tags: calculus, area

I have to find area enclosed by the curve $$x^6-x^2+y^2\le0.$$
I tried to convert the curve into polar form by substituting x=rcosθ and y=rsinθ to then use the formula$$Area = \frac{1}{2}\int_\beta^\alpha r^2\,dθ$$ but couldn’t proceed much. How to solve this question?

Comment: Please use tex to format your question to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: I made it more clearer now.

Comment: $$Area=\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{x^2-x^6}}^{\sqrt{x^2-x^6}}\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x$$

Comment: Hints: Transform to $\displaystyle\int_0^1 x\sqrt{1-x^4}dx$, you want to simplify $1-x^4$ so set $x^2=\cos(t)$ and it will results in easy calculation. Then the final area is how many time this integral ?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+sqrt%28x%5E2+-+x%5E6%29

Comment: Following zwin's hint (or setting $x^2=\sin t$), you should find [Area = $\frac\pi2$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5B2+sqrt%5C%2840%29Power%5Bx%2C2%5D-Power%5Bx%2C6%5D%5C%2841%29%2C%7Bx%2C-1%2C1%7D%5D).

Comment: I got it thanks.

Comment: [plot](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLU7BVKC4sKtGoiDNS0FWoiDPT5OUqyMkv0dBI01HQTdPUUdDQNdRRMAQy0osyU3Iy81KLbZVyE7Pyi5Q0ARXlEVw=&lang=sage)

Comment: I prefer to substitute $x^2=y$ and then notice that the obtained integral  
gives  the area of a part of the unit circle.

Comment: I've voted to leave open on the strength of the terse sketch of trying polar coordinates.  However you should make it a practice in the future to show what the result of your attempt is.  Readers cannot tell where you might have missed a step, etc. without more details of your attempt.